# Can't run c++ build task in VSCode

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-code

I have this code in VSCode:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build first program",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "firstprogram.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

which is pretty much the exact same code in the official guide to debugging, but it says that `g++ is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`. Pretty much all of the rest of my code is copied from the official thing, aside from code specific to my program, and I have the MinGW c++ compiler.

Comment: Do you have the path to the g++ executable in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @ifconfig If this is what you are talking about, then yes. C:\\Users\\21nalex\\Documents\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++

Comment: You need to have the `[MinGW Directory Path]/bin` in your path variable instead, as the `g++` executable is there.

Comment: @ifconfig So i now have this: 
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:/Users/21nalex/Documents/MinGW/bin/g++.exe"

Comment: and it still doesnt work

Comment: You need to put it in the system Environment Variable `$PATH` instead of the VS Code Browse Path

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the location of the `g++` executable to your computer's `$PATH` Environment Variable.

**To do this:**

1. Open up the start menu and search for "*Environment Variables*".
2. Click on the "*Environment Variables*" button at the bottom
3. Under "*System Variables*", click on "*Path*" and then click on "*Edit*"
4. Click on "*New*", and then type the path to your MinGW installation's bin directory. *From what you have told me in the comments I believe yours is* `C:/Users/21nalex/Documents/MinGW/bin`

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but how do I get to the start menu?

Comment: There is a start button on your keyboard, and one at the edge of your taskbar.

Comment: If this works for you, please upvote and accept my answer, @V.Largig